# Is translation vector in Cross Calibration of camera and LiDAR equals to physical distance in millimeters?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, calibration, lidar

I have an RGB camera and a LiDAR. I implemented a paper to cross-calibrate them in order to fuse their data.

The cross-calibration gives a rotation matrix (R) and a translation vector (t) to move points from the Lidar coordinate system to the camera coordinate system.

**My question is this:**
is the translation vector (t) equal to the distance between the center of the lidar and the camera when we use a ruler?

For example, if t=[23, 450, 300], does it mean in the x direction we should move 23 mm (millimeters), in y we should move 450 mm, and in the z-direction, we should move 300 mm?

I asked this question because the projection of LiDR point-cloud to an image seems pretty good in my eyes; however, the translation vector (t) has a significant difference when I use a ruler to measure the distance between the two sensors.

Comment: The measures are in the same unit of your provide "object points" during calibration. Can you explain in more detail how you performed the calibration?

Comment: I used this one: https://github.com/acfr/cam_lidar_calibration, @Micka

Comment: Did you measure, set and verify the parameters pattern_size, square_length, board_dimension and translation_error?

Comment: @Micka I checked pattern size, square length and etc. in t vector [x, y, z] of two sensors are as follows: x and y are match real distance of two sensor when I use a ruler, however z is not correct. In reality it is 600 mm however, the algorithms says 300 mm.

Comment: How did you measure the z-distance? The sensor position is the optical center, which might not be what you assume it to be (like the center of the sensor device housing). What's the focal length of your camera-lens-system?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.quora.com/Can-the-optical-centre-of-a-lens-be-outside-it with the 200 mm.example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if t=[23, 450, 300], does it mean in the x direction we should move 23 mm (millimeters), in y we should move 450 mm, and in the z-direction, we should move 300 mm?

-> yes it is as long as you have used the same unit to represent your point cloud during the optimization.

The reason why your estimation and the actual device distance are different might be because of the observability issue. Did you make enough motion or use enough data to observe the translation space well?

Small translations between the sensors might not make a notable difference if the scene points are far from the sensor. That might be why your result doesn't look too bad.

See my paper for more detail:
Spatiotemporal Camera-LiDAR Calibration: A Targetless and Structureless Approach